# How do I build a program with profiling that uses the text library?

Tags: haskell, build, profiling, ghc

I'm building a program that links to the [text](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-0.11.0.1) library.  When I build it without profiling, everything works fine:

```
ghc -O2 buildtrie.hs -package text -package hamt -o buildtrie -auto-all -package text -package hamt -fforce-recomp
<No output>
```

When I build it *with* profiling, I get the following error:

```
ghc -O2 buildtrie.hs -package text -package hamt -o buildtrie -auto-all -package text -package hamt -fforce-recomp -prof
ld: library not found for -lHStext-0.10.0.0_p
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I installed a profiling version of text-0.11.0.1 through cabal, but it doesn't seem to be finding it.  I'm guessing that text-0.10.0.0 was installed with Haskell Platform.  A `ghc-pkg list text` gives me the following:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/6.12.3/lib/ghc/package.conf.d
/Users/jason/.ghc/i386-darwin-6.12.3/package.conf.d
   text-0.10.0.0
   text-0.11.0.1
```

How can I compile this program using the profiling version of text-0.11.0.1?

Comment: `text` is not in the Haskell Platform at the moment; both listed versions look to be locally cabal-installed, as E Z Yang presupposes.

Answer (score 3):

What's likely happening is that one of the other dependencies you are pulling in depends on an old version of text, which is why it is being preferred. It's hard to say for certain, though, because you don't appear to be using Cabal.

An easy stop-gap is to reinstall text-0.10.0.0 locally with profiling.

```
cabal install --reinstall text-0.10.0.0
```

(assuming you've frobbed your .cabal configuration correctly; otherwise, add appropriate flags.)

Comment: I use cabal to install packages, but for this project I'm just using ghc (as using cabal seemed like overkill).  This is mostly just a benchmark program.